# CodeIgniter CLI - passing multiple args to method

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, command-line-interface

I'm testing out some models from a CodeIgniter project via CLI, the method in question has two arguments:

```
public function get_questions_from_block($block_name, $return_array = FALSE)
```

I have tried this:

```
php index.php test_controller get_question_block_name example_block TRUE
```

but it returns 0 or FALSE. How do I pass multiple arguments through CLI ? Do I have to use :

```
$_SERVER['argv'];
```

to get all the arguments? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) rather than `$_SERVER['argv']`

But in this case, I don't think that will help you (without heavy code modification).

Perhaps you should check out the [`unit-test` class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/unit_testing.html) that CI provides.

In that, you could simply run a series of tests against your model by doing something like the following in a separate unit testing file:

```
$this->load->model('test_model');
$this->unit->run(
    $this->test_model->get_questions_from_block(args),
    $expected_behavior /* what should be returned */,
    $test_name /* name your test */
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I really should be writing unit-tests on this piece of code anyway, It's great that codeigniter has a unit-test class shipped with the framework.

Comment: You can always use [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/) too. Personal preference I guess.